# boolean expression must not be null | Getting this error when i switch timerState to "true". "False" doesn't give an error, what went wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, boolean-expression

I am getting bool value timerState through the constructor. When I print the value I get proper results (true or false).
I need to call the function _controller.start() when timerState() == true. However when it is true I get the error: "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null".

Surprisingly, when timerState is false, I am not getting this error.
Please help, where can be a problem.
Below is my code:

```
  class PieChart extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;
  final String userName;
  final bool timerState;
  final Key key;

  PieChart(
      this.userId,
      this.userName,
      this.timerState,
      {this.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PieChartEmotionsState(
        userId,
        userName,
        timerState,
      );
}

class PieChartEmotionsState extends State {
  final String userId;
  final String userName;
  final bool timerState;
  final Key key;

  PieChartEmotionsState(
      this.userId,
      this.userName,
      this.timerState,
      {this.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();
    int _duration = 10;

    bool getTimerState() {
      print('PIE CHART timerState: $timerState');
      return timerState == true;
    }

    if (getTimerState()) {
      _controller.start();
    }


    return Container(...
```

I have obviously tried a simpler way:

```
if(timerState) _controller.start();
```

even this:

```
if(timerState ?? false) _controller.start();
```

But it seems not to have any impact on the issue. I am getting the same error...

What could be the solution?
Many thanks in advance for your support.
Dan

Comment: What is the stack trace from the assertion?  It likely is not complaining about your `timerState` variable, and your code doesn't use `assert`.  Find the `assert` that it's referring to, see what variable is null, and work backwards to figure out why it's null when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The issue here was os Olga wrote - the variable was not initialized so it was null and that's why I was getting an error. Could you please write here how can you get a stack trace information from the assertion simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need co create copies of your widget classes variables in the State class. Access them as `widget.variable`

> ```
> class PieChart extends StatefulWidget {
>   final String userId;
>   final String userName;
>   final bool timerState;
>   final Key key;
>
>   PieChart(
>       this.userId,
>       this.userName,
>       this.timerState,
>       {this.key});
>
>   @override
>   State<PieChart> createState() => _PieChartState();
> }
>
> class _PieChartState extends State<PieChart> {
>
>   bool getTimerState() {
>     print('PIE CHART timerState: ${widget.timerState}');
>     return widget.timerState == true;
>   }   
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();
>     int _duration = 10;
>
>
>     if (getTimerState()) {
>       _controller.start();
>     }
>
>
>     return Container(...
> ```

and make sure you initialize `timerState` when creating your `PieChart` widget as it's declared final.

```
 PieChart('userId', 'userName', true);
```

If you don't initialize it, it's set to null and the error you get is because you are checking if `null == true` in your `getTimerState()` method.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Olga :) Indeed, when I initialized timerState variable in State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PieChartEmotionsState(userId, userName, false) I stopped getting boolean expression error (is it the right place for initialization? - I stopped getting an error but _controller.start() still doesn't start. Btw, if I remove copies of widget class variables from State class, I cannot access them - widget.variable doesn't work...

Comment: `null == true` shouldn't generate any error; it'd just evaluate to `false`.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Initialization of timerState comes from StreamBuilder in the other widget - it fetches data from firebase and builds the Pie Chart with its builder. All other values work properly. However in this case, when I print:  print(timerState); I get result: true (so it seems the variable is initialized) but the expression in the next line: 
if (timerState) _controller.start();
returns boolean expression error as timerState was null..

Comment: sorry if that was unclear, by widget.variable i meant accessing any field from state class e.g. widget.timerState etc.
please see how i used it in my edit to your code snippet

Comment: then, if you created PieChart with false value for timerState it won't change, because it's a final variable. So your method getTimerState() will return false and _controller.start(); won't be invoked.

if you need to change widget's timerState, don't make it final

Comment: Olga, that was perfectly clear what "widget.variable" meant :) I just wrote that when I remove copies of variables from state class, I cannot access any variable via widget.timerState or widget.userName. None of these work.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. No matter timerState is final or not, it shouldn't generate boolean expression error when its true, should it?

Comment: See the edited answer, this should do it for widget and state to recognize each other.
Also why would you put method getTimerState() inside of build() method?
Maybe consider showing the whole project. I'm pretty sure i could help if i knew more of what are you actually trying to do

Comment: Thank you Olga for your support. I did stacktrace as @jamesdlin suggested and it turned out that the problem with boolean expression is not in my code but in _controller.start() method which was the third party widget taken from outside (circular countdown timer). I am not sure why it threw an error only when timerState was true (and not when it was false) but over the night I just removed this timer from my project and used simpler one ie Timer from dart async library. Everythink works now. Without animation but does the job for now. Many thanks for everyone for your input.